Understanding ごとに in ～種類ごとに分ける
I am bit confused about the meaning of ごとに in this sentence

服を下着や寝間着など種類ごとに分ける。

In one of my previous questions, in 区分特性ごとに区分する, the meaning of 区分特性ごとに is clear: for each characteristic. However, I cannot translate 種類ごとに in the above sentence as "for each type" but as "in each type." This discrepancy has been bothering me.
I think the reason for such discrepancy is that in 区分特性ごとに, に turns 区分特性ごと into an adverb modifying 区分する (this is the same に used in 本当に). On the other hand, the に in 種類ごとに is just a simple destination marker for verb 分ける. XをYに分ける means to divide X into Y. Now I am not sure about the meaning of ごと in 種類ごとに. I think it is bit different from the one in 区分特性ごとに. Perhaps, it means それぞれ?

Edit: Judging from the comments by @aguijonazo, Xごとに does not always translate "for each X." The meaning of ごとに discussed in this question seems to correspond to this definition from Meikyou:

❶ それを一つの単位として物事が行われる意を表す。そのものに応じて。「分野━に色分けする」「クラス━の出展」

Xごと means "treating X as a unit that makes up a whole."
So in 区分特性ごとに区分する, 区分特性 is a unit that makes up a set of 区分特性s. In 種類ごとに分ける, 種類 is a unit that makes up a set of 種類s.
Some other examples of this ごと:

グループごとに集まる: gather in groups

四年ごとの開催: hosting [of some event] that happens every 4 years

曜日ごとの担当者: person in charge which differs each weekday



Without complicating anything too much, I believe it should be translated to "seperate them into all the different categories like underwear and bedwear"

If you see 種類 as a column in a database table and 下着, 寝巻き, etc. as its values, 種類ごとに分ける corresponds to doing GROUP BY 種類. In your previous question, 区分特性 is a meta-concept that refers to multiple such columns and 区分特性ごとに区分する means you do GROUP BY 色, 酸味, etc. where the order is determined by 優先順位. Although に may be working differently, ごと itself seems to refer to constituents of a whole in both cases. You could simply say 種類で分ける, though.

@aguijonazo Interesting analogy. You are saying that 区分特性 is a database table with multiple columns? 種類ごとに分ける uses a single database table while 区分特性ごとに区分する uses multiple database tables?

No, one table has multiple columns such as 色 and 酸味 and 区分特性 is just a general term to refer to those columns.

@aguijonazo Then there is a possibility that some items need to be duplicated? There are items that can belong in one of the columns 色 and one of the columns 酸味.

No, items constitute rows in a database table. Each item (i.e. row) has some value in each of the columns, such as "yellow" for the 色 column and "strong" for the 酸味 column.

I see, thanks. This is a nice analogy that helps me to see that both 区分特性ごとに and 種類ごとに are very similar.
